# Is this sentence correctly constructed for the meaning one is trying to convey?

Tags: meaning, sentence, syntactic-analysis

Here is the sentence:

> Techi's brother Data is Painting Dye's husband, Time Line's best friend.

The sentence before that establishes that Time Line is Painting Dye's husband. The meaning trying to be conveyed in this sentence by my friend is that Techi's brother Data is Time Line's best friend, and Time Line being Painting Dye's husband should be re-established.

After careful analysis of this sentence, I have been unable to see how this exact wording conveys the meaning. However, my friend doesn't believe that this sentence cannot convey the intended meaning. Does anyone have a way to convince him of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[These names are very hard to read, so I'm hyphenating them.]

> Techi's brother Data is Painting-Dye's husband, Time-Line's best friend.

What your friend thinks he has written is

> [Techi's brother Data] is [Painting-Dye's husband Time-Line]'s best friend.

But as written and pointed here, with the comma after *husband*, the sentence puts the phrase *Time-Line's best friend* in apposition to the phrase *Painting-Dye's husband*. It will be parsed

> [Techi's brother Data] is [PaintingDye's husband], [TimeLine's best friend].

That is

- [Techi's brother Data] is [Painting-Dye's husband], *WHO IS ALSO*
- [Time-Line's best friend].

All three of these bracketed entities are the same person.

Simply striking the comma will help; but it will make the sentence ambiguous instead of flat wrong.

Your friend needs to recast the sentence in a way which clearly distinguishes the people and their relationship. For example:

> Techi's brother Data is the best friend of Painting-Dye's husband, Time-Line.

Comment: I'd just analysed 'is Painting Dye' as a wrongly capitalised present participle structure!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Me too. I'm gonna go back and hyphenate them, for some approach to intelligibility.

Comment: Of course, I used to think StoneyB was a wrongly capitalised adjectival.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's honest. I was named after Gen. Jackson, and 'Stoney' was my stage name for 30 years.

Comment: This is great! Thanks. I hadn't thought of bracketing the sentence to show him the problem. Accepted.